# Create view query not working

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

This the problem in my book that I am trying to solve..I need to create this report..

A list of the programs on all channels for a specific day showing the channel number, supplier, package, program name, rating code, and show time. This will be similar to a program guide, only not package specific. This is a date-driven report, therefore it should only display programs for a single date specified.

I tried this so far..

```
CREATE VIEW PROG_LINEUP AS
SELECT DISTINCT
  PC.PROGTIME AS `SHOWTIME`,
  P.PROGNAME AS `PROGRAM TITLE`,
  C.CHID AS `CHANNEL #`,
  SU.SUPNAME AS `SUPPLIER`,
  R.RATING AS `RATING`
FROM
  PROG_CHAN PC,
  CHANNELS C,
  SUPPLIERS SU,
  PROGRAM P,
  CHANNEL_PACKAGE CP,
  RATING R
WHERE
  PC.SHOWDATE = '18-DEC-10'
  AND P.PROGID = PC.PROGID
  AND CP.CHID = PC.CHID
  AND R.RATINGID = P.RATINGID
  AND C.CHID = PC.CHID
  AND SU.SUPID = P.SUPID
ORDER BY PC.CHID;
```

But it's giving this error when the table Prog_chan exists! I checked.. What is wrong?
Please tell me if any table script is required. Please help...

```
WHERE PC.SHOWDATE = '18-DEC-10' AND
*
ERROR at line 13:
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

I cant figure out what is wrong since Prog_chan table exists and has values too in it..

```
QL> desc prog_chan;
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
CHANID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
PROGID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
SHOWDATE                                  NOT NULL DATE
STARTTIME                                 NOT NULL DATE
```

@Jeff -

I removed that comma but error is this now...

```
CHANNEL_PACKAGE CP, * ERROR at line 11: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: So do you have a table or view called CHANNEL_PACKAGE in your schema?

Comment: `PROGRAM TITLE` is not a valid column name for a table, neither for a view. Be careful when naming your view fields

Comment: And also, a friend's advice: use [SQL JOINS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). You learn once, and use throughout your entire life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an erroneous extra comma before the WHERE clause.

```
RATING R,
WHERE PC.SHOWDATE = '18-DEC-10' AND
```

Comment: I removed that comma but error is this now... CHANNEL_PACKAGE CP,
*
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @Geeko:Check for your `grants` on that table,do you have `select` grant on that table ,if the table dosent exist in your schema then check if `synonyms exist` for your that table of not .